# Is there a way to save (balanced) tree , for fast loading/creation

Tags: c#, tree

i have a tree data structure, building the tree can take a long time (more than a hour),
as it is been build with many data from DB.
i'm looking for good solution to save the tree state after the first build, so that i well be able to perform load instead of creating it again.
the main idea is to have some kind of an image of the tree, for the option of fast creation, and for debug.
it is implemented in C#.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What takes so much time in building the tree?

You can always save a flat string of the tree using a techinque that you can see here:
[Saving a Binary tree to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005784/saving-a-binary-tree-to-a-file)